# How to know when editText ends being editted?

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have two `editText`s and when the user edits one and then hits done, it executes a method. I want to be able to know when the user stops editing it. Like in that case, with hitting the "done" button. Unfortunately, the user can 'stop' editing it, if he/she selects the other `editText`. For some strange reason, the OnEditorActionListener doesn't catch that case. What can I do about it? I've tried with onFocusChange, but that one is very unpredictable...

Comment: Why can't you make the other one not enabled until the done button is pressed if you don't want them typing in it?

Comment: Because that would make the user experience less likeable. I'd like to find a better way to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can assume when the EditText looses focus

```
EditText txtEdit= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edittxt);
txtEdit.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {          
    public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
        if(!hasFocus)
        //probably here! 
    }
});
```

Comment: When the view gets loaded and the user clicks on one of the edittexts, it gets focus, loses it and gets it again, after that the user gets to type. Which would mean my method would get executed before the user can type.

Comment: if I understood it, you can check if the one that lost focus has text